Orientation and movement of my robot model reversed in rviz
I have an issue with rviz displaying the motion of the robot model reversed when connected to the actual robot. The physical robot responds correctly to forward and backward , left and right commands using a joystick. In rviz, the robot responds to left and right as forward and backward. Forward and backward as left and right. My camera image is also upside down and my lidar scan is also reversed in the opposite direction. The robot is a differential drive robot. I am using ROS foxy.
How to flip the camera image, laser frame and the forward backward, left and right motion so the model responds in the same way as the physical robot?

You are probably publishing the wrong tf, try to view the tfs in rviz and look if they are in the correct position and orientation according to your base link.

Can I change the orientation in my urdf.xacro? I am a newbie so I am not sure.

yes you can. I dont know how you publish your tfs but most of the time there is a 'robot_state_publisher' node that takes the urdf file as input and publish the tfs using  tags in the urdf file. The joint tags determine the orientation and position of various links relative to each other using  tag with xyz for position and rpy for orientation. Now in your urdf file you probably have them. Try to find the intended tags and fix them by displaying in rviz.
